# How can I programmatically display the "Create Features" dockable window in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, development, .net

When I start editing in ArcMap 10, by default the "Create Features" window is automatically opened and docked. Stopping the edit session hides this window.

When I use the IEditor:StartEditing method this does not display the "Create Features" window however if it is already displayed the IEditor:StopEditing method hides it.

How can I Start Editing programmatically and display the "Create Features" window?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick (C#):

```
  var dockableWindowManager = (IDockableWindowManager)_app; // _app is an IApplication reference
  var uid = new UIDClass() { Value = "esriEditor.CreateFeatureDockWin" };
  var window = dockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(uid);
  window.Show(true);
```